# How many six digit wavy numbers can be formed from the numbers 1 to 6.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A book was quoting that a 'wavy number' is a number where the digits alternately get larger and smaller (or smaller or larger). For example, using all the digits 1, 2, ..., 6, 163524 and 634152 are 'wavy numbers', but 126543 is not.

How can you determined how many possible six-digit wavy numbers there are give the digits 1, 2, ..., 6. Can this be generalised to using 1, 2, ..., n?

Comment: We can start by searching 1st group of wavy-numbers : High-Low-High-Low-High-Low. And we have one subset : If High are (4,5,6) and Low are (1,2,3), this subset is easy to count. The other subset is when High are not (4,5,6), more complex to count.

Comment: I tried starting with high and then low, but as Lourrran said high doesn't necessarily have to include 4, 5, 6. I then wondered if it could just be a combination - i.e. is there only one way to arrange a set of numbers that make it wavy - if you started with 6, then is there only one possible arrangement?

Answer (score 0):

Take two functions $U(n,m)$ and $D(n,m)$.  $U(n,m)$ is the number of $n$-digit numbers starting with $m$, then going up.

First, by symmetry,
$$U(n,m)=D(n,n+1-m)$$
Also, after $m$, there are $n-1$ numbers left.  Relabel $m+1,\ldots,n$ as $m,\ldots,n-1$, and $$U(n,m)=\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}D(n-1,k)$$
The total seems well-approximated by
$$Total(n) \approx \frac8\pi\left(\frac2{\pi}\right)^nn!$$
and $U(n,m)$ seems proportional, as a function of $m$, to $\cos(m\pi/(2n))$

Answer (score 0):

I think we have to count manually.

Starting with $6.5$, no solution.

Starting with $6.4.5$, we need to have $3$ in 5th position, so $2$ solutions.

Starting with $a.b.c$, the greatest remaining number must be in 5th position, so maximum $2$ solutions, and maybe $1$ or $0$.

Starting with $a.b.c$, if all remaining or $2$ remaining numbers are less than $c$, there are $2$ solutions, if $1$ remaining numbers is less than $c$, there is $1$ solution, and if no remaining number is less than $c$, no solution.

So $6.4.5$ --> $2$ solutions

$6.3.5$, $6.2.5$, $6.1.5$, $a.b.6$ : $2$ solutions for each.

$28$ solutions at this step.

How many solutions starting with $a.b.4$ , with $a>4$ ? $6 \times 2$ solutions.

How many solutions starting with $a.b.3$ , with $a>3$ ? $6 \times 1$ solutions.

How many solutions starting with $a.b.5$ , with $a<5$ ? $6 \times 2$ solutions.

How many solutions starting with $a.b.4$ , with $a<4$ ? $3 \times 1$ solutions.

$28+12+6+12+3=61$ solutions, starting with High.

Plus similar $61$ solutions, starting with Low.